# use proguard for android project always got error?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I have a problem with using proguard, this first time I learned proguard, I use [this](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#) and more link to make proguard but I have not been able to implement to my project,in my app  I use libs google_play_services and actionbarsherlock. I kept trying and the result is always error. I had 2 days looking for how I can use proguard in my project, this time I was really confused, I need proguard in my application, this screenshot of my app (app_run).

[image]

this my proguard setting

```
    -optimizationpasses 5

    #When not preverifing in a case-insensitive filing system, such as Windows. Because this tool unpacks your processed jars, you should then use:
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames

    #Specifies not to ignore non-public library classes. As of version 4.5, this is the default setting
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

    #Preverification is irrelevant for the dex compiler and the Dalvik VM, so we can switch it off with the -dontpreverify option.
    -dontpreverify

    #Specifies to write out some more information during processing. If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
    -verbose

    #The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and 1.5 can't handle. Note that the Dalvik VM also can't handle aggressive overloading (of static fields).
    #To understand or change this check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/optimizations.html
    -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

    #To repackage classes on a single package
    #-repackageclasses ''

    #Uncomment if using annotations to keep them.
    #-keepattributes *Annotation*

    #Keep classes that are referenced on the AndroidManifest
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
    -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
    -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
    -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


    #To remove debug logs:
    -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
        public static *** d(...);
        public static *** v(...);
        public static *** i(...);
    }

## ActionBarSherlock 4.4.0 specific rules ##

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*

## hack for Actionbarsherlock 4.4.0, see https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/1001 ##
-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.internal.**

## Google Play Services 4.3.23 specific rules ##
## https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard ##

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}


    #To avoid changing names of methods invoked on layout's onClick.
    # Uncomment and add specific method names if using onClick on layouts
    #-keepclassmembers class * {
    # public void onClickButton(android.view.View);
    #}

    #Maintain java native methods 
    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        native <methods>;
    }

    #To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML.
    #Uncomment if having any problem with the approach below
    #-keep public class custom.components.package.and.name.**

    #To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML:
    -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
        public <init>(android.content.Context);
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
        public void set*(...);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    }

    #Maintain enums
    -keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }

    #To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
    }

    #Keep the R
    -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
        public static <fields>;
    }
```

could anyone help me to give a way how to use proguard for my application?

really need help,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Proguard is going to require "rules" for the libraries you use, and possibly your own code too.  Many of these rules can be found https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries

Comment: above I use proguard with extra setting based on your link but still error, where I had to fix it?

Comment: You're going to have to share an error.  You have to identify the error and then figure out which rules you're missing.  You're going in position should be to identify every library and check their support site for rules required to make Proguard work.

Comment: Just a guess, but you're probably missing Proguard rules for ActionBarSherlock ;)  Hell, and 1/2 a dozen others.  You have your work cut out for you, but that doesn't change the answer.  Identify the errors and find the right Proguard rules.  It's not easy.

Comment: so I had to find a way to fix the rules libs? what about the others? it is correct?

Comment: I don't know how else to say this: you can look for proguard rules for all the libraries you're using or you can play whack-a-mole in LogCat via find an error, fix an error.  There's no easy path.  You're just going to have to try harder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75561/discussion-between-ltvie-and-bill-mote).